# Is it possible to change the variable value for a coroutine started during ViewModel initialization

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a Kotlin coroutine that I initialize in a Viewmodel class. Something like this

```
init {
     viewModelScope.launch {
        person.retrievePersonsWithId(<ID VARIABLE>).collect {
            _persons.value = it
        }
    }
}
```

Is this `<ID VARIABLE>` changeable based on UI. What I want to be able to do is have this Kotlin coroutine continuously running. When the UI text changes be able to change that `<ID VARIABLE>` so that the coroutine automatically picks it up without having to cancel the above coroutine and recreate a new one.

Comment: How do you observe this `<ID VARIABLE>`? Can you acquire a flow of ids?

Comment: Its just a basic String variable currently that lives in the ViewModel, I am open to changing it up as well, the string basically is anything that user enters in view layer.. something like a fragment for Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we need a way to observe changes to this `<ID VARIABLE>`, preferable in a form of another flow of ids. There are multiple ways to create such flow, it depends on your specific case. One of the easiest is to store the id inside a [MutableStateFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-state-flow/index.html):

```kotlin
private val idFlow = MutableStateFlow(<initial value>)

// change ID value:
idFlow.value = 42
```

We use this `idFlow` as a source of IDs. Then we need to use [flatMapLatest](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-latest.html) to re-initialize another, resulting flow using `retrievePersonsWithId()` whenever the ID changes:

```kotlin
idFlow.flatMapLatest { person.retrievePersonsWithId(it) }.collect {
    _persons.value = it
}
```